# temporary boost::bind inside another boost::bind doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like your opinion on this one, what is going on ?

consider this code:

```
void DilateLine(LightMap& lmap, LightMap& copy, int y, boost::function<bool(int, int)> const& applicationPredicate)
{ /*...*/ }

boost::function<bool(int, int)> predicate = boost::bind(&LightMap::IsOverPaddingSpace, lmap, _1, _2);
Executor e(params, boost::bind(DilateLine, boost::ref(lmap), boost::ref(copy), _1, boost::ref(predicate)));
```

This compiles fine.
But, this does not:

```
Executor e(params, boost::bind(DilateLine, boost::ref(lmap), boost::ref(copy), _1, boost::bind(&LightMap::IsOverPaddingSpace, lmap, _1, _2)));
```

> 1>C:\local\boost_1_56_0\boost/bind/bind.hpp(457): error C2664: 'void
>   (LightMap &,LightMap &,int,const boost::function &)' :
>   cannot convert argument 4 from 'bool' to 'const boost::function &'

over boost code:

```
template<class F, class A> void operator()(type<void>, F & f, A & a, int)
{
    unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_], a[base_type::a3_], a[base_type::a4_]);
}
```

If I follow the chain of "referenced from here" I arrive on the code line mentioned under "this does not".

This changes nothing, that I remove the `const&` in the boost::function in the Dilate function.
Why do you think, one of these two forms does not compile ? When they are actually equivalent, I simply created a named rvalue instead of a temporary to fix the build.

Comment: This is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841857/vc2013-function-from-bind-not-compiling/25842919#25842919 except with `boost::bind` instead of `std::bind`.

Comment: @T.C. thank you, I search before asking but the title of the question you link is not expressive enough to be found from the problem. Thankfully you are aware of it by memory, let's keep the link here for the future. Still, I don't understand your answer over there :) develop on `what's going to end up being passed to the function you are binding is the result of invoking that bind expression` ?  'd be very appreciated :)

Comment: Basically, in your second block of code, it will try to pass the result of calling `lmap.IsOverPaddingSpace(<first argument>, <second argument>)` as the last argument to `DilateLine`.

Comment: Ok that's perfectly clear, and explains the compiler message. But are you also able to explain why it does that ?

Comment: Because they think it's a nice feature to allow you to compose functions this way.