# moving lambdas using std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I get a compilation error (`error C2064: term does not evaluate to function taking 0 arguments`) when compiling this code in visual studio 2013

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class F>
void foo(F& callback)
{
    callback();
}

template<class F>
void bar(F& callback)
{
    auto barCallback = std::bind([](F& callback)
    {
        callback();
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }, std::move(callback));

    foo(barCallback);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("hello ");
    auto f = std::bind([](std::string& s) { std::cout << s; }, std::move(s));
    bar(f);
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to achieve here is to *move* the `std::string` from `main` into `bar` and then into `foo` (without making copies)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda

Comment: That is where I got the idea for using std::move with std::bind :), but now I am stuck with this compilation issue.

Comment: You are running into [the special handling of `bind` for bind expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841857/vc2013-function-from-bind-not-compiling/25842919#25842919). You need to wipe out the type somehow - e.g., via a `std::function`.

Comment: I verified that using `bar(std::function<void()>(f))` in `main` solves the issue. Unfortunately, this means the string is copied into the `std::function`, and that is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Comment: And `std::ref` doesn't work?

Comment: `std::ref` doesn't work for multi-threaded scenarios. For instance, if `foo` was called on a separate thread. I need the ability to _move_ state into another thread.

Comment: Then consider writing your own wrapper.