# std::bind as an argument to std::bind

Tags: c++, function-pointers, multimap, std-function, stdbind

I have the following code:

```
static std::vector<std::multimap<float, std::function<void(void)> > > LoadedDelegates;

std::function<void(FVector2D, std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)>)> ShooterFunc = [this](FVector2D Input, std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)> InputFly)
{
    this->RemainingFlies.Add(this->MakeShooterFly(Input, InputFly));
};

LoadedDelegates.push_back(std::multimap<float, std::function<void(void)> >
{
    {
        3.f,
        std::bind(ShooterFunc, FVector2D(1.f, 0.f), std::bind(&ASwatterLevelBase::ShootAndScootMisdirection, this, std::placeholders::_1, FVector2D(0.f, 0.f), 8))
    }
});
```

I have a bind inside of another bind to convert from `std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)> >` to `std::function<void(void)> >`. This snippet of code won't compile. However, if I move the bind into a variable and pass it like this:

```
static std::vector<std::multimap<float, std::function<void(void)> > > LoadedDelegates;

std::function<void(FVector2D, std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)>)> ShooterFunc = [this](FVector2D Input, std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)> InputFly)
{
    this->RemainingFlies.Add(this->MakeShooterFly(Input, InputFly));
};

std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)> TestFunc = std::bind(&ASwatterLevelBase::ShootAndScootMisdirection, this, std::placeholders::_1, FVector2D(0.f, 0.f), 8);

LoadedDelegates.push_back(std::multimap<float, std::function<void(void)> >
{
    {
        3.f,
        std::bind(ShooterFunc, FVector2D(1.f, 0.f), TestFunc)
    }
});
```

it works. Why do I have to pass in the second bind as a variable in this case for it to compile?

Comment: I realized that my issue is probably that std::bind can't deduce what my return type is when it's used in the first example. So now I tried to cast the std::bind like so:
`std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)>(std::bind(&ASwatterLevelBase::ShootAndScootMisdirection, this, std::placeholders::_1, FVector2D(0.f, 0.f), 8))`
However, I get this error:
`error C4868: compiler may not enforce left-to-right evaluation order in braced initializer list`
How can I explicitly cast the std::bind?

Comment: Although now that I think of it, the first std::bind is evaluated correctly, so I'm not even sure now.

Comment: Alright, it would seem that the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841857/vc2013-function-from-bind-not-compiling/25842919#25842919) would be the issue I'm having, and would explain why the first example doesn't work, because I need to wrap it in a std::function if it's a bind that's an argument in a bind. But that leads back to my previous comment with regards to casting; how would I wrap the bind in an std::function so that it would compile?

Answer (score 0):

So as I mentioned in one of my question's comments, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841857/vc2013-function-from-bind-not-compiling/25842919#25842919) was the reasoning behind why this was happening. What I wanted to do was be able to add in bind arguments inside of a bind without creating new variables everytime. I came up with a suitable solution by doing this:

```
static std::vector<std::multimap<float, std::function<void(void)> > > LoadedDelegates;

std::function<void(FVector2D, std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)>)> ShooterFunc = [this](FVector2D Input, std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)> InputFly)
{
    this->RemainingFlies.Add(this->MakeShooterFly(Input, InputFly));
};

std::function<void(ASwatterFly*)> DummyFunc;

LoadedDelegates.push_back(std::multimap<float, std::function<void(void)> >
{
    {
        3.f,
        std::bind(ShooterFunc, FVector2D(1.f, 0.f), DummyFunc = std::bind(&ASwatterLevelBase::ShootAndScootMisdirection, this, std::placeholders::_1, FVector2D(0.f, 0.f), 8))
    },
    {
        6.f,
        std::bind(ShooterFunc, FVector2D(-0.2f, 1.f), DummyFunc = std::bind(&ASwatterLevelBase::LaserShooter, this, std::placeholders::_1, this->GetVecFromScreenPercentage(0.15f, 0.9f), 1, 0.f, 0.f, 3.f, 260.f, 0.f, FLinearColor(15.f, 3.f, 3.f)))
    },
    //etc.
});
```

So I can just use DummyFunc to wrap the bind without having to create a variable for each new bind in the multimap.